# prolog " how to answer this query"

Tags: prolog

a) Write a predicate heads/2 ( a r g l , arg2) that takes an instantiated list of lists in argl and that computes as arg2 the list of heads of the sublists. For example:

```
?- heads([[3, 8], [9], [1, 2, 3], [a, b, c]], L).    
L = [3, 9, l, a]
```

b) Define mply to take two inputs; an integer and list of integers. The result is a list of
integers formed by multiplying each integer in the list by the input integer. For example:

```
?- mply(5, [1, 2, 3], X).    
X = [5, 10, 15]
```

c)Write a Prolog program called compute (Expr, Value) that will compute the
value (Value) of an arithmetic expression Expr. The requirement are as follows:
• An arithmetic expression is either a single number or a list in the form [Exprl,
Operator, Expr2]
• Exprl and Expr2 are arithmetic expressions
• Operator is either the atom plus or the atom minus.
Your program should work for the following queries:

```
?- compute(7, Val).
Val = 7

?- compute([2,plus,[9,minus,1]], Val).
Val = 10
```

I'm doing revision about prolog and very appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: It would be useful if you could give some answers to those questions yourself, i.e. what you *think* the answers are, so that the community knows which bit(s) you're stuck on. I'm guessing you know some of the answers at least (as you're at the revision stage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a) and b) you are required to traverse a list and perform a simple computation. General list traversal works as follows:

```
list_traverse([]).
list_traverse([H|T]) :- list_traverse(T).
```

Hence, in general your solutions should add input and output to the schema above.

Specifically, for a)

```
heads([],[]).
heads([H|T],[HH|TT]) :- H = [HH|_], heads(T,TT).
```

and for b)

```
mply(_,[],[]).
mply(X,[H|T],[HH|TT]) :- HH is X*H, mply(X,T,TT).
```

c) requires a slightly more elaborate processing since you have to distinguish between addition and subtraction:

```
compute([Val],Val) :- number(Val).
compute([E1,plus,E2],Val) :- compute(E1,V1), compute(E2,V2), Val is V1+V2.
compute([E1,minus,E2],Val) :- compute(E1,V1), compute(E2,V2), Val is V1-V2.
```

Comment: thank you very much,i never learn traverse and compute in my lecture, might be in the next class, i will ask my lectures, and again, thank you very much, very very appreciate your help :)

Comment: Why not `heads([[H|_]|T], [H|TT]) :- heads(T, TT).` ?

Comment: @Boris: your solution will also work. I've tried to work in a more 'didactic' way by separating the list traversal schema from the processing of the list head.

Comment: It is probably a matter of taste, but there is nothing "didactic" in unnecessary explicit unification in the body if it can be done in the head. On the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

ad a) What does it mean to compute the head of an empty list? I assume that the predicate should then fail:

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

list_heads(XXs, Xs) :-
   maplist(\[X|_]^X^true,XXs, Xs).

mply(F, Xs, Zs) :-
   maplist(F+\X^Z^(Z is X*F), Xs, Zs).

compute([I],Val) :-
   Val is I.
compute([E1,plus,E2],Val) :- compute(E1,V1), compute(E2,V2), Val is V1+V2.
compute([E1,minus,E2],Val) :- compute(E1,V1), compute(E2,V2), Val is V1-V2.
```

Note that `compute([_],V)` will now issue an `instantiation_error` which is a much better idea than failing silently.